# list of mapped drives you have USED. get the suggestion list for mapping

Tags: windows-7, windows, network-shares

USING the GUI
today when I map network drives, click on the path for the drive and list of suggestions appear (past mappings),  I am migrating my laptop and I want that list.   any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Are you referring to what essentially amounts to the **Run** command history?  If so, you can find it here:  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU`

Comment: Yeah, the question is not clear on what gui they are using.

Answer (score 1):

That list can be found at:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Map Network Drive MRU
```